# PHP Create ZIP file in background

Tags: php, background, zip, download

I am using the following script to create zip files: http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

It's working just fine and does exactly what I need. Sometimes though I have large files and zipping those takes up to 30 seconds.
I want to let the user know that their download is being packed and tell them whenever the download is ready.
How would I do that? I have a script which is called download.php which basically just calls this create_zip method from above and then forces a download like this:

```
$files = explode(":", $file_decrypted);

array_pop($files);

$zipname = 'uploads/download_' . $username . '.zip';

foreach ($files as &$value) {
    $value = "uploads/" . $username_d . "/" . $value;
}

$resultat = create_zip($files, $zipname, 'uploads/' . $username . '/');

ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();

// Start the download for the user
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
exit();
```

So basically I want to show a text to the user (For example: Preparing download...) and at the same time call all the above php stuff in the background somehow.

Comment: You could pack the zip from another php and call it through an ajax call, meanwhile you could display a progress bar or a loading icon

Comment: How would I do this ajax call? I don't have any Ajax experience :(

Comment: You could google some ajax tutorial, it will be really helpful to develop dynamic websites :), and it's not really hard